# Is it possible to complete tags when searching questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

When writing a question, tags can be completed just by starting to write a word.
However when searching for questions with specific tags, input like "[bla" does not complete.
I wonder how difficult an implementation would be, meaning: I'd consider such completion being very useful.

Comment: The same feature has been in place for posting questions.

Comment: A bit clunky, but the input field under "The following tags:" in the form that shows up when clicking the Filter button on the Questions page does provide automatic completion. Though, as far as I can tell, it requires you to apply the filter first and add your keywords to the search bar as a second step.